# Set default Map with saturation in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

When setting the map options to:

```
Map.setOptions( 'HYBRID', {'HYBRID':[ { featureType:'all', stylers:[{saturation:-100}] },]  }  );
```

It creates the map as an option to be clicked in the user interface but does not set it as the default map.

How do I set it to be the default display map style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
    Map.setOptions( 'HYBRID', {'Grey':[ { featureType:'all', stylers:[{saturation:-100}] },]  }  );
    Map.setOptions('Grey')

or 

    Map.setOptions( 'Grey', {'Grey':[ { featureType:'all', stylers:[{saturation:-100}] },]  }  );
```

Thanks to Gennadii Donchyts on the developer earth engine forum.